# Identically distributed random variables and events of probability $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X_1,\dots,X_{n+1}:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Suppose that the random variables are identically distributed, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}\circ X_1^{-1}(B) = \ldots = \mathbb{P}\circ X_{n+1}^{-1}(B), \ \ \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$$ Also suppose that there exist real-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that,$$(\mathbb{P}\circ X_1^{-1})(\{x_1\in \mathbb{R}: f(x_1)\not = h(x_1) \}) \stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=} \mathbb{P}[\{\omega \in \Omega :f(X_1(\omega))\not = h(X_1(\omega))\}] = 0.$$ Now consider the remaining random variables as a random vector $X(\omega) = (X_2(\omega),\ldots , X_{n+1}(\omega)):\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to prove that, $$(\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1})(\{(x_2,\ldots , x_{n+1})\in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x_2)\not = h(x_2), \ldots, f(x_{n+1})\not = h(x_{n+1}) \}) \stackrel{\text{(2)}}{=} \mathbb{P}[\{\omega \in \Omega :f(X_2(\omega))\not = h(X_2(\omega)),\dots , f(X_{n+1}(\omega))\not = h(X_{n+1}(\omega))\}] = 0.$$ I don't know whether $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true but anyway, here is my proof.

**My try:** Note that $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega \in \Omega :f(X_2(\omega))\not = h(X_2(\omega)),\ldots , f(X_{n+1}(\omega)) \not = h(X_{n+1}(\omega))\}] = \mathbb{P}[B_2 \cap \ldots \cap B_{n+1}],$$ where $B_j = \{\omega \in \Omega: f(X_j(\omega))\not = h(X_j(\omega))\}$ and $j=2,\ldots , n+1$. We know $\mathbb{P}[B_j] = 0$, since random variables are identically distributed, and that the events of probability $0$ are independent of all other events. So this implies that, $$\mathbb{P}[B_2 \cap \dots \cap B_{n+1}] = \mathbb{P}[B_2]\ldots \mathbb{P}[B_{n+1}] = 0.$$

Is this reasoning correct? Is it possible to use this line of reasoning with push-forward measure $\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}?$ The push-forward measure assigns probability to a vector of real numbers, so I don't know how to describe the correct subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and apply the measure to it.

Comment: What you did is right. Actually you've used the push-forward measure in the last equality since (\mathbb{P} \circ X^{-1})(B_2 \times \cdots \times B_{n+1}) = \mathbb{P}(B_2 \cap \cdots B_{n+1}).

Comment: @Captuna Is that really used? I think I've used only the definition of independent events.

Comment: In the last equation, you don't need independence, just use the intersection is the subset of any $B_j$ so one $P(B_j) = 0$ is enough. The rest are correct, it's called the  change-of-variables formula (wiki: pushforward measure). For example, write (1) as an integration with a indicator function.

Comment: This is a false statement in general, but it becomes true if you assume $f$ and $h$ are measurable functions. In that case, the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=f(x)-h(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is also measurable and so (since $X_1, ..., X_n$ are identically distributed) we know $g(X_1), ..., g(X_n)$ are identically distributed. So $P[g(X_i)=0]=P[g(X_1)=0]=1\quad  \forall i$. The explanation of why it is false in general takes a bit more work and it is not clear if you care about the nonmeasurable $f,h$ case.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. It would be great if you explain that case (maybe in an answer if you like, so I can accept it) because I don't see why $f$ and $h$ need to be measurable. Also, are the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ in my answer correct? How can they be proved?

Comment: @Michael As a side note, according to LNT's comment, we need only one $\mathbb{P}(B_j) = 0$ but it seems unintuitive to me since the other $B_j$'s could be any other event. Even we can select other random variables with arbitrary distributions!

Comment: LNT is correct, if $B, C$ are any events that satisfy $P[B]=0$ then $$B \cap C \subseteq B \implies P[B \cap C] \leq P[B]=0$$

Comment: Yes your equations (1) and (2) are correct.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Does it need a proof? It seems to me that they are self-evident by the definition of push-forward measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a false statement in general, but is true if you assume $f$ and $h$ are Borel measurable functions. The LNT comments above are correct if you assume Borel measurability (which is a common assumption).

For simplicity, define $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)-h(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Setup:**

You have identically distributed random variables $X_1, ..., X_n$ with $n\geq 2$. You have a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and you are told $P[g(X_1)\neq 0]=0$. You want to evaluate $P[\cap_{i=2}^n\{g(X_i)\neq 0\}]$.

**Case 1 - Suppose $g$ is a Borel measurable function:**

Then $g(X_1), g(X_2), ..., g(X_n)$ are identically distributed and so
$$P[g(X_i)\neq 0] = P[g(X_1)\neq 0] = 0 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}$$
As noted in comments above by LNT (who was implicitly assuming this measurable case) we have
$$\cap_{i=2}^n \{g(X_i)\neq 0\} \subseteq \{g(X_2)\neq 0\} \implies P[\cap_{i=2}^n \{g(X_i)\neq 0\}]\leq \underbrace{P[g(X_2)\neq 0]}_{0}$$
and since probabilities cannot be negative, we obtain the desired result
$$ \boxed{P[\cap_{i=2}^n \{g(X_i)\neq 0\}]=0}$$

**Case 2 (counter-example when $g$ is not Borel measurable):**

Fix $n=2$. Strange fact: It is possible to have two random variables $X_1:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $X_2:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$ on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ that are both uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, but with disjoint images:
$$X_1(\Omega)\cap X_2(\Omega) = \phi$$

See "Strange uniform random variables" by D. Rizzolo here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7148

Assuming such strange uniform random variables $X_1, X_2$, define the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{ if $x \in X_1(\Omega)$} \\
1 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then
$$ \{g(X_1)\neq 0\} = \phi \implies P[g(X_1)\neq 0]=0$$
$$ \{g(X_2)\neq 0\} = \Omega \implies P[g(X_2)\neq 0] = 1$$
In view of Case 1, it is clear that this counter-example cannot occur unless $g$ is nonmeasurable. This means that $X_1(\Omega)$ is not Borel measurable. Indeed, the only way to get these strange uniform random variables is if their images are not Borel measurable sets.

**Note: Proving $g(X_i)$ are identically distributed:**

**Claim:** If $X,Y$ are identically distributed random variables and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable, meaning that
$$ g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
then $g(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are identically distributed.

**Proof:** Fix $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $g$ is Borel measurable, we know that $g^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. So $\{g(X)\in B\} = \{X \in g^{-1}(B)\}$ is a valid event, as is $\{g(Y)\in B\}$.

Then we have
\begin{align}
P[g(X)\in B]&=P[X \in g^{-1}(B)]\\
&\overset{(a)}{=}P[Y \in g^{-1}(B)]\\
&=P[g(Y) \in B]
\end{align}
where (a) holds because $X, Y$ are identically distributed.
$\Box$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So it seems that it's sufficient to have only $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed (the distribution of other random variables is irrelevant). Is my understanding correct? Also I don't see at which step in my reasoning, the measurability of $f$ and $g$ is used. Would you point it out, please?

Comment: Yes, to prove the intersection has zero probability, it is enough to prove $P[g(X_2)\neq 0]=0$. The place where measurability is used can be seen from the last note in my answer above. You cannot necessarily talk about $g(X_i)$ as a random variable if $g$ is not measurable, equivalently, $\{X_i \in g^{-1}(B)\}$ is not necessarily a valid event if $g^{-1}(B)$ is not a Borel measurable set.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So my understanding is as follows. In order to $(\mathbb{P}\circ X_1^{-1})(\{x_1\in \mathbb{R}: f(x_1)\not = h(x_1) \})$ be well-defined, we need that the set $\{x_1\in \mathbb{R}: f(x_1)\not = h(x_1) \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable set. Is this correct?

Comment: I've asked a question about the equations (1) and (2). I would appreciate your help if you could answer. It seems to me that they are true by the definition but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$ and so we can only take probabilities of sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Your equations (1) and (2) try to do two steps at once and it is not helping, you cannot take probabilities of sets that are not events. If I remove your probability operation then (1) and (2) are true by definition of "inverse image" of a function.  They are similar to saying for $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that  $$X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} := \{X \in B\}$$

Comment: I summarized my understanding. Do you think it is correct now? $$$$
If $f$ and $h$ are Borel measurable functions then $A = \{x_1\in \mathbb{R}: f(x_1)\not = h(x_1) \}$ is a measurable set, i.e., we have $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Since $X_1:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, the set $X_1^{-1}(A) = \{\omega\in \Omega: X_1(\omega)\in A \}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$...

Comment: ... Note that $X_1(\omega)\in A$ is equivalent to $f(X_1(\omega)) \not = h(X_1(\omega))$. So we have, $$X_1^{-1}(A) = \{\omega\in \Omega: f(X_1(\omega)) \not = h(X_1(\omega)) \} \in \mathcal{F}$$ and the probability of this set is $\mathbb{P}[X_1^{-1}(A)] = \mathbb{P}[X_1\in A]$ which is by definition same as $(\mathbb{P}\circ X_1^{-1})(A)$.

Comment: Yes, looks good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help.